# unable to bind observable array - knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have a observableArray named **simpleSearchResultsArray** which contains the data, and the array **gridOptions** which contains the table header names. The code for the same is at : http://jsfiddle.net/FENuV/8/

The view code:

```
<table id="resultTableBody">

    <thead id="resultTableHeader">
        <tr style="text-align: center" data-bind="foreach: columns">
            <th style="text-align: center" data-bind="visible: checked, text: header">
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody  data-bind="foreach: simpleSearchResultsArray">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: $parent.gridOptions.columns">
            <td  data-bind="text: $parent[dataMember], visible:checked">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

View model code:

```
function QuoteSimpleSearchVM() {
    var self = this;

        self.gridOptions = {
        columns: [{
            header: 'Index',
            dataMember: 'index',
            checked: ko.observable(true)
        }, {
            header: 'Job Name',
            dataMember: 'jobName',
            checked: ko.observable(true)
        }, {
            header: 'Quote Name',
            dataMember: 'quoteName',
            checked: ko.observable(true)
        }, {
            header: 'Quote Number',
            dataMember: 'quoteNumber',
            checked: ko.observable(true)
        }, {
            header: 'Bid date',
            dataMember: 'bidDate',
            checked: ko.observable(true)
        }, {
            header: 'Last modified',
            dataMember: 'lastModified',
            checked: ko.observable(true)
        }, {
            header: 'Document Type',
            dataMember: 'docType',
            checked: ko.observable(true)
        }, {
            header: 'Status',
            dataMember: 'status',
            checked: ko.observable(true)
        }, {
            header: 'View',
            dataMember: 'view',
            checked: ko.observable(true)
        }
       ]
    };

    self.simpleSearchResultsArray={
        Result:[{
        bidDate: "07/11/2013",
        docType: "QUOTE",
        index: 1,
        jobName: "MobileTestingReportGenerationJob",
        lastModified: "07/11/2013",
        quoteName: "MobileFunctionalQuote",
        quoteNumber: "ftcc06000_06241300_01_00_O00",
        status: "Pending Quote Approval" 
        }, {
        bidDate: "08/28/2012",
        docType: "QUOTE",
        index: 2,
        jobName: "_Aug28th_GLOBAL_CHANGE",
        lastModified: "07/11/2013",
        quoteName: "32259_Purify",
        quoteNumber: "ftfs04000_08281200_07_00_O00",
        status: "Draft"
        }
    ]};
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var tempVM= new QuoteSimpleSearchVM();
    ko.applyBindings(tempVM.gridOptions, document.getElementById("resultTableHeader"));
    ko.applyBindings(tempVM.simpleSearchResultsArray, document.getElementById("resultTableBody"));
});
```

I am getting binding error. Can anyone help me with the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you bind `tempVM.gridOptions` to node? You must bind your view model instead. And just add `with` to `<thead id="resultTableHeader" data-bind="with: gridOptions">`.

Look out here: http://jsfiddle.net/kreeg/FENuV/9/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how can i display the data which is part of simpleSearchResultsArray array? Can you modify the jsfiddle for that ? Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/FENuV/11/

Comment: Your `simpleSearchResultsArray` is not array, it's object. Use `simpleSearchResultsArray.Result` instead. Check here  http://jsfiddle.net/kreeg/FENuV/12/

Answer (score 1):

You dont need call ko.applyBindings twice. Call it on parent node, and bind foreach on     your objects.

```
<tr style="text-align: center" data-bind="foreach: gridOptions.columns">
```

and

```
<tbody  data-bind="foreach: simpleSearchResultsArray.Result">
```

[Look out here](http://jsfiddle.net/ash_bars/FENuV/14/)